# Images not embedding in PDF

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I have a problem that is doing my head in.

I am generating a PDF with CFs `<cfdocument format="pdf" ...`

Easiest way to explain this problem is to take a look at this PDF.

http://www.essendondpc.com.au/_temp/referrals/referral_120208085540.pdf

You will notice in the top right there are 4 images.  Two are not embedding properly, and 2 are.

Here are the image tags for the images:

```
<!---NOT DISPLAYING--->
<img src="http://www.essendondpc.com.au/_images/globalMarkBlack.jpg" width="100">
<img src="http://www.essendondpc.com.au/_images/submit.gif" width="100">

<!---ARE DISPLAYING--->
<img src="http://www.a-s-a.com.au/_images/banners/asa2012_tall.jpg" width="100">
<img src="http://www.sunburyonline.com.au/Classifieds/photos/IMG_3796.JPG" width="100">
```

The images are sitting on the server, but for some reason, the 2 images sitting at the domain that the PDF is being generated at are not embedding.  I just can't work out why.

Any suggestions to keep me off the cliff of insanity are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jason

Comment: Have you tried `localUrl=true` in `<cfdocument>`, and use relative path?

Comment: Henry, nice!  I didn't even know about that paramater.  I have done as you suggested and it worked a treat.  Still unsure why I was having problems with one domain and not the other, but I will happily put that down to a strange http quirk.  If you can post your suggestion as the answer I will happily flag it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `localUrl=true` in `<cfdocument>`, and use relative path?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and was able to resolve it using this syntax:

```
<img src="file:///C:/websiteDirectory/images/imagename.jpg" />
```

Since this change was made no errors occur and the images always display. I store the 
"file:///C:/websiteDirectory/images/" as an application variable and call it as:

```
<img src="#application.pdfImgDir#imagename.jpg" />
```